# Bundler update dependencies clash

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Each time I update gems with bundler I got something I really do not fully understand. Although it resolves in some way in the end :)
So in this example I really can't get why the 1.11.1 is not fit in the constrains:
1.11.1 is >= 1.3.3
and >= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0
and ~> 1
and ~> 1.3
right?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    nokogiri (= 1.11.1)

    cuprite (~> 0.8) was resolved to 0.8, which depends on
      capybara (>= 2.1, < 4) was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)

    s3_uploader was resolved to 0.2.3, which depends on
      fog-aws (>= 0.9.4) was resolved to 3.5.2, which depends on
        fog-xml (~> 0.1) was resolved to 0.1.3, which depends on
          nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)

    mimemagic (= 0.3.10) was resolved to 0.3.10, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1)

    cuprite (~> 0.8) was resolved to 0.8, which depends on
      capybara (>= 2.1, < 4) was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
        xpath (>= 2.0, < 4.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
          nokogiri (~> 1.3)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What's your Ruby version? Bundler selects compatible gem versions also based on the required Ruby version of the respective gem version.

Comment: Nokogiri 1.11.1 as enforced by your `Gemfile` is only compatible with Ruby < 3.1. With a newer Ruby, you have to update your nokogiri. This is likely a good idea in any case since there were a lot of security updates since this old version.